# Is it dangerous to clone,warning about Permanently added '' to list of known hosts?

Tags: git

I tried to clone repo from github(to see how Golang and react work together)

```
 git clone git@git.bec-systems.com:cbrake/goreact.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/cbrake/goreact
Cloning into '/home/miki/go/src/github.com/cbrake/goreact'...
The authenticity of host 'git.bec-systems.com (159.65.229.70)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:CzPCk6/fsCvAD1xG9GiHswVWHyOvB0/UD7da7CWzTTk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added 'git.bec-systems.com,159.65.229.70' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@git.bec-systems.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Are there any repercussions for me? What does it mean that git was added to the list of known hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH server uses certificate to identify itself to client. When you are first connecting you will add the fingerprint to `known_hosts` from that time if somebody steals that domain and try to redirect you to other ip he will need to get copy of server certificate you saved if not ssh will die on that the server certificate changed. [REF](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key)